# Multiple typo3 instances but one fe_users table

Tags: typo3, instances

I face the issue, that I would like to work with multiple typo3 instances that access only one fe_users table from one "primary" instance. The idea is to "plug" typo3 instances on a primary instance but that the plugged typo3 instances are not having an own fe_users management.

The instances are not necessarily running the same version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be best to use a single sign on solution for this or a central directory. Since every TYPO3 instance could have a different structure of the fe_users table, there will be problems using a single database table. Another option would be to synchronize the records with a cronjob between the instances.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing a similar problem and think about the usage of an OpenID server to solve it. Typo3 has support for it since 4.3 I think.

A native SQL based support is unknown to me. Of course a custom extension might does the trick which might be a good idea, considering the disadvantages of the current core login extension.

Another way may be the usage of LDAP. Both OpenID and LDAP may not be the direct approach you asked for but it might gives you the hint needed.

Edit:

- http://wiki.openid.net/w/page/12995226/Run-your-own-identity-server
- http://www.webworking-blog.de/content-management/typo3/typo3-openid-fur-das-login/

cu

Roman